# Which is better - $H_3$ Hamming code, or $\hat{H_3}$ extended Hamming code.

Tags: coding-theory

My question is, which is better - $H_3$ Hamming code, or $\hat{H_3}$ extended Hamming code. The reason that I ask is that the $P_{err}$ for the two are equal, so the chance of error between the two is the same. I am unsure why one would use the extended code for this reason.

One reason I was thinking, was the extended code is a $[8,4,4]$ code, verses a $[7,4,3]$ code - so the extended can correct an additional error. However, at the same time the extended codes are of length $8$, so that extra error correction seems to be redundant.

Thanks for any help in being able to understand which would be better.

Comment: Better for what?

Comment: (By the way, *verses* are the lines of a poem, while *versus* is what you had in mind)

Comment: The extended Hamming code cannot _correct_ an extra error; it _detects_ when two errors have occurred (without saying where the errors are).

Comment: The answer will probably depend on the application. For example on the channel, on whether soft decision decoding is available, whether you can make any use of the double-error-correcting capability of the extended code...

Comment: In addition to Leonbloy's useful answer you may be interested in reading what I wrote about [comparison between two other codes in MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/97646/15503). Also, don't forget to read what Dilip Sarwate added there - using a more complicated receiver may again change the verdict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions "which code is better?" cannot be answered, in general, unless you specify a goodness criterion. In regards to error correction/detection, for a forward error correcting code (ie. with no feedback) there are several measures:

1 Up to how many error bits can it correct?

2 Up to how many error bits can it detect?

3 How many errors bits in a burst can it detect?

4 What is the the probability of erroneous decoding $p(err)$? (assuming some statistical model for the channel, usually BSC - and some decoding strategy -usually hard ML)

Whichever goodeness measure you choose among these ones (or any other), it should also be combined with other factors: mainly code rate and decoding complexity.

The extended Hamming Code $(8,4)$ can be preferable to the classical Hamming Code $(7,4)$ if we are interested in error detection (criterion 2): it can detect up to 3 erroneous bits - and even then, the advantage should be weighted against the disadvantage (lower rate). It is not preferable if we are interested in error correction (criterion 1).